# Explode array results and echo.

Tags: php, arrays, split, return, explode

Have been working on a small project, and have gotten stuck at a part that I am trying to get working. Not sure if I am taking the wrong type of approach for it, and there is a better way, but here we go.

I have data in a text file that is written and read to.
example: (values are separated by a \t)

```
S1684    This is a status    share   20/9/2012           share;
```

What I am doing is searching the file, and returning anything that matches as a part of the array. I have the search working fine, and can return each line that contains the search query, only problem is exploding the results so that I can properly format what I return. This is the main chunk that deals with it.

```
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches)){
       echo "<h3>Results:</h3>";

       echo implode("<p>\r\n", $matches[0])."</p>";

       foreach ($matches as &$value) {
        $date =0;
         list($statusCode, $status, $share, $date, $like, $comment, $share) = explode("\t", $date);

         echo "<h4>Status:".$status."</h4>";
         echo "<h4>Status Code:".$statusCode."</h4>";
       }

    }
```

The error I receive are undefined offset errors, so how exactly would I be able to explode (or split the array result in any other way) to echo it properly?

Any help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `$matches[0]` be a string? Can you `implode` a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `explode("\t", $value);` instead of `explode("\t", $date);`

You are using `$value` for holding the current value of the array during iteration. `$date` is always being assigned 0 in the iteration, and trying to explode it will be causing the error.

Comment: Oh derp I am an absolute idiot bahaha thanks for pointing out the obvious -_-